# 2D object grids to a dictionary

Tags: c#, unity

I'm pretty new to Unity and trying to figure out what a good way of transferring objects in a grid to a dictionary would be.

For example, if i have a grid of 2D objects (squares) such as below

```
-------------
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
-------------
    | 3 | 4 |
    ---------
    | 5 |
    -----
```

I would expect my dictionary to be something like

```
myDict =
{
 {"0", 1},
 {"1", 0, 2, 3},
 {"2", 1, 4},
 {"3", 1, 4, 5},
 {"4", 2, 3},
 {"5", 3}
}
```

What i want to do is generate a random grid and then make a dictionary of neighbors of each grid piece that i can later use for other purposes.

Being new to Unity, i'm not really sure what a good way of this would be.

Comment: An array of lists would do this even better, probably. What about Unity is stopping you from doing this?

Comment: I'm confused as to how this dictionary maps to this grid?

Comment: @KellyThomas it maps as key=object name value=neighboring object names

Comment: @Ben I guess I'm just trying to find out what would be a good way of doing this.In other words, if i have grid piece at Vector3(0,0,0) and one right next to it at (1,0,0) how can i add the one at (1,0,0) to the dictionary (or list you suggested) as neighbor of (0,0,0) one.  Would i have to look at the position x of the objects or somethhing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm assuming that you're creating your random grid inside of a two dimensional array.

```
int[,] grid = new int[5, 5];
int lastVal = 0;

Random r = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    int startCol = r.Next(0, 5);
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        //-1 indicates that the node is empty
        grid[i, j] = j >= startCol ? lastVal++ : -1;
}
```

After creating the grid, you should discover the neighbors and fill your map accordingly.

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> valueToNeighborListMap = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        if (grid[i, j] != -1)
            valueToNeighborListMap[grid[i, j]] = discoverNeighbors(grid, i, j);
```

Boundaries need to be checked in order to avoid from index out of bounds exception.

```
private List<int> discoverNeighbors(int[,] grid, int row, int col)
{
    List<int> neighbors = new List<int>();

    bool canGoLeft = col > 0;
    bool canGoRight = col + 1 < 5;
    bool canGoUp = row > 0;
    bool canGoDown = row + 1 < 5;

    if (canGoUp && grid[row - 1, col] != -1)
        neighbors.Add(grid[row - 1, col]);
    if (canGoLeft && grid[row, col - 1] != -1)
        neighbors.Add(grid[row, col - 1]);
    if (canGoDown && grid[row + 1, col] != -1)
        neighbors.Add(grid[row + 1, col]);
    if (canGoRight && grid[row, col + 1] != -1)
        neighbors.Add(grid[row, col + 1]);
    if (canGoUp && canGoLeft && grid[row - 1, col - 1] != -1)
        neighbors.Add(grid[row - 1, col - 1]);
    if (canGoUp && canGoRight && grid[row - 1, col + 1] != -1)
        neighbors.Add(grid[row - 1, col + 1]);
    if (canGoDown && canGoLeft && grid[row + 1, col - 1] != -1)
        neighbors.Add(grid[row + 1, col - 1]);
    if (canGoDown && canGoRight && grid[row + 1, col + 1] != -1)
        neighbors.Add(grid[row + 1, col + 1]);

    return neighbors;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, i actually had my objects in a `List<GameObject>` and just assigning their `transform.position` values within a nested `for` loops to get the grid look.  Having it in 2D array seems more manageable.

Comment: thanks! i was able to translate this to the way i am doing it with a `List<GameObject>` as opposed to 2D array.  Because of this my `discoverNeighbors` is a little different but same concept.